# How to use Contains key method of Dictionary that a part of key string but not complete key string in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I have a concurrent dictionary whose key is string type and value is a class type, Now some function in my code file adds values to Dictionary, that is key be Complete file name on windows machine and value be a my class type.

Now what i was trying to do is i have a part of complete file pathname based on this I want to check if concurrent dictionary contains any value for that if yes then I want value for it else nothing to do.

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Record> RunningExportDic
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Record>();

private MethodResult GetExportStatus(string CameraFolderPath)
    // Here CameraFolderPath is a part of complete key string
    // which was added to dictionary.
{
    MethodResult mResult = new MethodResult();
    i2V_Record obj_i2vRecord = null; 

    if (RunningExportDic.ContainsKey(CameraFolderPath))
    {
        obj_i2vRecord = RunningExportDic[CameraFolderPath];
    }           

    if (obj_i2vRecord != null)
    {
        if (obj_i2vRecord.isExportSuccessfully && obj_i2vRecord.isThreadClosed)
        {
            mResult.Result = ResultMessage.SUCCESS;
            mResult.Obj_Result = "Exorted Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            mResult.Obj_Result = obj_i2vRecord.statusString;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mResult.Obj_Result = "Error";
    }
    return mResult;
}
```

Comment: You could use the `RunningExportDic.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains(..))` but this destroys the whole use of the dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries are fast because the keys are hashed and divided into buckets. It allows you to quickly find a subset of keys with the same hash, and then it will do a proper comparison to actually match an exact key. That is, many keys _can_ have the same hash, but overall few keys should have the same hash, so it will be faster. Partial matches mean that this system can't really be used, so the performance if you use the method Jeroen describes will reduce it to the same as accessing a regular list.